# Local Variable Not Initialized Inside While Loop

Tags: java

I'm stumped at the compile time error: `The Local Variable may not have been initialized`. I declared and initialized the local variable `doc` before use, and as far as I know it exists in the same scope as the `doc` in the while loop. I've seen several questions on the topic on SO, but most of them deal with not initializing the variable, which doesn't seem to be my problem. I would really appreciate your help.

I declare the method `arrayIntKey` in an abstract class, and pass a txt file from `main`. The error occurs inside the while loop.

```
protected KeyValue[] arrayIntKey(int size,File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner doc = new Scanner(file); 
    Integer key;
    String value;
    KeyValue[] intKey = new KeyValue[size]; 
    int index=0;
    while (doc.hasNext()) { //ERROR: local variable doc may not have been initialized
        key = doc.nextInt();
        value = key.toString();
        intKey[index]= new KeyValue(key,value);
        ++index;
    }
    return intKey;
}
```

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable and method names should always start with a lower case character.

Comment: I second that. Ensure that you use Java naming conventions when posting on this site.

Comment: Yeah, you have an argument named **File** of type **File**, this may cause the compiler to wrongly interpret the initialization of **doc**.

Comment: Which line is throwing you the compilation error?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code that does not compile?

Comment: make sure you close `Scanner` (unrelated but still)

Comment: The lines referring to doc give compilation error eg `doc.hasNext()` and `key = doc.nextInt()`

Comment: Thank you @Ossin Java guy, that fixed my problem. I will accept as answer if u post it

Comment: You haven’t initialised key & value

Comment: @nitnamby there's a write before the read - there is no problem there.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an argument named **File** of type **File**, this may cause the compiler to wrongly interpret the init of **doc**.

Just use camel case convention:

```
protected KeyValue[] arrayIntKey(int size,File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Comment: Afaik it shouldn't. It's always totally clear to the compiler due to order "first type, then name". Thus, Java doesn't restrict the name to start with upper-case. It simply doesn't matter for the compiler.

Comment: @st4rgut which java version are you using?

Comment: java runtime environment 1.8.0_144 using Eclipse Oxygen IDE